# Get the value from attribute in details view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my partial View Preview.cshtml

```
@model MonitoreoIntegrado.Models.Figuras

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tipo)

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.nombre)

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.size)

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.color)

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.borde)

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.colorBorde)

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.rotacion)
```

the model.size data type is short. I need to get the value of model.size to do something like this

```
<div style="width:@(model.size*2); height:@(model.size*3)"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `Model` instead of `model` ? in the parts where you aren't using a lambda

Answer (score 0):

like @Pricey said. it was just write Model.attribute instead model.attribute. Thanks!
This is the implemented code :)

```
@{    
int largo = (Model.size-Model.borde).Value;
double centro = Model.size*1.42/2;
short x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4, deg;
deg = Model.rotacion.Value;
x1=(short)Math.Round(centro + (largo*1.42/2) * Funciones.coseno(225 - deg));
y1 = (short)Math.Round(centro + (largo*1.42/2) * Funciones.seno(225 - deg));
x2 = (short)Math.Round(x1 + largo * Funciones.coseno(90 - deg));
y2 = (short)Math.Round(y1 + largo * Funciones.seno(90 - deg));
x3 = (short)Math.Round(x2 + largo * Funciones.coseno(0 - deg));
y3 = (short)Math.Round(y2 + largo * Funciones.seno(0 - deg));
x4 = (short)Math.Round(x3 + largo * Funciones.coseno(270 - deg));
y4 = (short)Math.Round(y3 + largo * Funciones.seno(270 - deg));
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="@(Model.size*1*42)" height="@(Model.size*1.42)">
    <polygon points="@x1,@y1 @x2,@y2 @x3,@y3 @x4,@y4"
         fill="#@Model.color" stroke-width="@Model.borde" stroke="@Model.colorBorde" />
</svg>
}
```

Funciones.coseno is like Math.cos but it works with degrees instead radians.